# Azure SQL database time issue

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a .net application running on a Azure server which is set to PST and it connects to a Azure SQL server set to UTC time.  I use the function getDate() in a lot of my stored procedures.  Going forward time zone is going to be a critical issue and need to have them both in sync.  Using the function DateAdd(hour, -8, getDate()) does not account for daylight savings time.  I was wondering if there was a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change all your `datetime` columns to `datetimeoffset(7)` columns.  These columns store timezone information with the date and the time.

Next change your `GETDATE()` calls to `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`.

Finally, you can convert the stored time information using the `AT TIME ZONE` keyword:

```
SELECT   *,
         [Time] AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AS PstTime
FROM     TheTable
```

- I've tried storing `datetime` values always in UTC (or any other arbitrary zone) and have ALWAYS run into issues.  After switching to `datetimeoffset(7)` nearly all my problems have been resolved.